# Is there any way to get the progress that a Stream or Future takes?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream

I have a Stream that calls several Futures, what I want is to know if there is a way to get the progress of a general Stream, for example in an application, when something is downloaded, it shows the percentage, however I want to do that, since my Stream are APIs requests and I want to show the user how much percentage of the 5 APIS calls are in the function.

[image]

For example, the first two functions will take from 0 to 40%, but I don't know if this should be static, or if it can be dynamic with the Streams or Futures.

Comment: i believe you had it done few days ago using `async*` generator?

Comment: With async* I could send static texts, but what I want is to get a dynamic percentage depending on a Stream or Future method.

Comment: "With async* I could send static texts" no, you can `yield ` whatever you want, post your current code

Comment: Yes, now I know that with yield I can send any value, what I want to know is if it can be obtained from another Stream function or Future its progress percentage, as I have it in the image.

Comment: inside `async*` generator you can `await` your API calls and `yield` its result

Comment: Are you saying you want each Future/Stream to report it's progress percentage before finishing?

Comment: Yep, or at least if it's exist some calculations to get the percentage